# Laravel - Trying to get property "id" of non-object while using POST Method

Tags: php, laravel, api

Am writing an endpoint with Laravel using using. When I tested on postman using POST Method, I got this error:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\testing-file\testing\app\Http\Controllers\ApiController.php on line 912

Controller

```
    public function storeBilling(Request $request)
    {
        // $billing = Billing::create($request->all());
        // return response()->json(['success' => $billing], $this-> successStatus);
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'network' => 'required'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        // Creating a record in a different way
        $createBilling = Billing::create([
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
            'network' => $request->network,
            'sender' => $request->sender,
            'recipient' => $request->recipient,
            'message' => $request->message,
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'billing_type' => $request->billing_type,
        ]);

        return new BillingResource($createBilling);      
    }
```

Model

```
class Billing extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'billing';

    protected $fillable = [
        'network' ,
        'sender',
        'recipient',
        'message',
        'timestamp',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'amount',
        'billing_type',
        'user_id',
        'service_name',
        'package',
        'email',
        'user_id'
    ];    


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Resource

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use App\Billing;

class BillingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'network' => $this->network,
            'sender' => $this->sender,
            'recipient' => $this->recipient,
            'message' => $this->message,
            'amount' => $this->amount,
            'billing_type' => $this->billing_type,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'service' => $this->service,
            'package' => $this->package,
            // Casting objects to string, to avoid receive create_at and update_at as object
            'timestamp' => (string) $this->timestamp,          
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at
          ];
    }
}
```

If I use this POST Method:

> http://localhost/testing-file/stesting/api/storeBilling?network=100

It suppose to post into the database, but I got this error:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\testing-file\testing\app\Http\Controllers\ApiController.php on line 912

Comment: try to check if this user exists in the db  'user_id' => $request->user()->id. its possible it could not get the id of the user before inserting into db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'user_id' => $request->user()->id`

Your error is saying that `$request->user()` is not an object, so you cannot access its parameters using object notation, e.g. `->id`.

If you `dd($request->user)` you may see that you are not getting what you thought you were getting - it may be an array, or it may not be the right value at all.

If it is an array, you can access the value like `$request['user']['id']`. It really depends what you are passing in your POST request.

Answer (score 1):

`$request->user()->id` is incorrect.

If you want the current user you can use `Auth::user()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your question you said you are trying to build an endpoint using Lravel ..

Postman will not have access to the user object unless authenticated, if authenticated then this should work ::

```
 $request->user()->id or Auth::user()->id or $request["user"]["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

on you

> public function storeBilling(Request $request)

You write `$createBilling = Billing::create([
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,` and this create error.

Or is preferable to have `$createBilling = Billing::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,` to find the id of the user authentificate.

don't forget to add `use Auth;` at the beginning of the controller

Answer (score 0):

Going through a same Hassle it's happening because relationship finding its relation with billing table but it did not find so giving this error please check your database have related entry's and try again and make sure you have right relationship with table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).